# GoogleMap Widget is not loading the coordinates

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a simple relationship

```
companies - contacts
            addresses
            locations
```

The details (contacts, addresses, locations) are on a separate page. Each of these details is a specific table. For locations, I have added a little google icon that opens up a map widget in a separate dialog/window. The separate dialog where google map widget is tied to locations datasource. It should be tied to the specific location row the user clicked on.

The details page is based on companies and each of these details is a table based on contacts/addresses/locations.

Is there a way for me to tell appmaker to use that specific location when the icon is clicked on? I am not sure how it manages to tie the location from a specific company to the dialog. I am guessing it does not.

Answer (score 0):

When user clicks the location icon the click event should be propagated to the row and the row with location you need should be selected. It means that you can achieve desired behavior just by playing with bindings. In theory something like this should make a trick:

```js
// binding for latitude
@datasources.Company.relations.Locations.item.Latitude

// binding for longitude
@datasources.Company.relations.Locations.item.Longitude
```